# C++ fill an empty buffer with a single value

Tags: c++, arrays

I apologize in advance if I am using the incorrect terminology, I'm new to the C++ language. I have a class with a constructor that creates an empty buffer using `malloc`

```
LPD6803PWM::LPD6803PWM(uint16_t leds, uint8_t dout, uint8_t cout) {
    numLEDs = leds;
    pixels = (uint16_t *) malloc(numLEDs);
    dataPin = dout;
    clockPin = cout;
}
```

My understanding is that this creates an empty buffer with the length of whatever I pass to `numLEDs` this is essentially a dynamically created array correct? I'm using `malloc` because this code goes on an Arduino that has very limited memory and I want to avoid overflows and from what I have read, this is the best way to declare arrays is you don't know what size the array will be and you want to avoid overflow errors.

My question is, once this array has been created is there a faster way than a traditional for loop to fill the array with a single value. Very often I will want to do this and even microseconds make a difference in this application. I know that from the C++ standard library array classes have a `fill` method, but what about an array declared in this way?

Comment: It's more normal to use `new uint_16_t[]` (or a `std::vector`) in C++ code, unless it's to be passed to code that expects to `free()` the memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is, once this array has been created is there a faster way than a traditional for loop to fill the array with a single value.

The C standard library provides `memset()` and related functions for filling a buffer. There's also `calloc()`, which allocates a buffer just like `malloc()`, but fills the buffer with `0` at the same time.

> Very often I will want to do this and even microseconds make a difference in this application.

In that case you might consider ways to avoid repeatedly allocating the array, which could take more time than filling an existing array. As well, the easiest way to make your code go faster is to run it on faster hardware. Arduino is a great platform, but Raspberry Pi Zero costs less ($5, if you can find them), has a LOT more memory, and has a clock speed that's 64x faster than a typical Arduino (1Ghz vs. 16MHz). Computing is often a tradeoff between good, cheap, and fast, but in this case you get all three.

Comment: memset will only work for byte-size value and at least gcc optimizes std::fill to memset when applied to char data.

Answer (score 1):

You can still use `std::fill` (or `std::fill_n`), most standard library implementations will delegate to `memset` for RandomAccessIterator (e.g. gcc and Clang). Trust in the standard library writers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [memset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/). But you have to be careful about the value you want to set. And you won't be much faster than using a `for` loop. The computer needs to set all these values somehow! `memset` may set larger contiguous memory spans and therefore be faster, but a smart compiler may do the same for a `for` loop.

If you're really concerned about microseconds you need to do some profiling.

Comment: Basic `memset` implementations are slower than `for` because operate on single bytes. However, this is rather uncommon as it's a very easy to optimize function and can get tenths of times faster (even hundreds) than a `for`.

Comment: @black A good compiler should get the same result for a loop with a constant assignment. I am interested, which optimization will enable a processor to set memory locations faster?

Comment: There would be a lot to say (ask if you need!). Basically, modern CPUs can work with large chunks of bytes (128, 256, 512) as if it were a single operation (SIMD). Moreover, they can compute these large stores in parallel / out-of-order (known as ILP - Instruction Level Parallelism) if they detect it's possible. And I've named just a few techniques. If you can take advantage of these capabilities, it  can get extremely fast. Look up these terms and maybe look into the [tag:performance] tag.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use memset from stdlib.h:

```
memset(array, 0, size_of_array_in_bytes);
```

Note however that memset works byte for byte,e.g it sets the first byte to 0 or whatever value you set as the second parameter, then the second byte and so on, which means that you must be careful.

Just a note:
malloc gets its size as the size of arrays in bytes, so you might consider multiplying its parameter by sizeof(uint16_t)